# LinkedList not working properly in gcc compiler

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So i am using mingwx64 compiler and vscode editor but display function is not working properly but when i try to display in main() function with same logic as arr.display() It works.
I tried running the same code on onlinegdb website and it was running as intended.
Is is a gcc bug or a feature i am not aware of ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class nodee
{
public:
    int data;
    nodee *next;
};
class ll
{
public:
    nodee **head = NULL;

    nodee **push(int no = 1)
    {
        nodee *node;
        int n;
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            node = *head;
            while ((*node).next != NULL)
            {
                node = (*node).next;
            }
            while (no--)
            {
                nodee *new_node = new nodee();
                cout << "Enter the element : ";
                cin >> n;
                (*node).next = new_node;
                new_node->data = n;
                new_node->next = NULL;
                node = (*node).next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nodee *first = new nodee();
            head = &first;
            node = *head;
            cout << "Enter the element : ";
            cin >> n;
            first->data = n;
            no--;
            while (no--)
            {
                nodee *new_node = new nodee();
                cout << "Enter the element : ";
                cin >> n;
                (*node).next = new_node;
                new_node->data = n;
                new_node->next = NULL;
                node = (*node).next;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
    void display()
    {
        nodee *node = *head;
        while (node->next != NULL)
        {
            cout << node->data<<endl;
            node = node->next;
        }
        cout<<node->data<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    ll arr;
    arr.push(5);
    arr.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a bug in your code, not in a compiler. Valgrind: `==14474== Use of uninitialised value of size 8 // ==14474==    at 0x1094FC: ll::display() (a.cpp:61) // ==14474==    by 0x109268: main (a.cpp:73)`

Comment: I am new to coding i didn't quite get it ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `head = &first;`, you are using a pointer to a local variable as `head`, which is invalid after the `push` function.

The solution is to make `head` only be a `nodee *`, you do not need the extra `*`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class nodee
{
public:
    int data;
    nodee *next;
};
class ll
{
public:
    nodee *head = NULL;

    nodee *push(int no = 1)
    {
        nodee *node;
        int n;
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            node = head;
            while ((*node).next != NULL)
            {
                node = (*node).next;
            }
            while (no--)
            {
                nodee *new_node = new nodee();
                cout << "Enter the element : ";
                cin >> n;
                (*node).next = new_node;
                new_node->data = n;
                new_node->next = NULL;
                node = (*node).next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nodee *first = new nodee();
            head = first;
            node = head;
            cout << "Enter the element : ";
            cin >> n;
            first->data = n;
            no--;
            while (no--)
            {
                nodee *new_node = new nodee();
                cout << "Enter the element : ";
                cin >> n;
                (*node).next = new_node;
                new_node->data = n;
                new_node->next = NULL;
                node = (*node).next;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
    void display()
    {
        nodee *node = head;
        while (node->next != NULL)
        {
            cout << node->data<<endl;
            node = node->next;
        }
        cout<<node->data<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    ll arr;
    arr.push(5);
    arr.display();
    return 0;
}
```

not working: https://godbolt.org/z/cr4rY4oKK

working: https://godbolt.org/z/88rd53jGP

Comment: Okay i get it 90% , i get it that there no ne for pointer to pointer variable but then why is it a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of the list does not make a sense.

Instead of declaring the data member `head` like

```
nodee *head = NULL;
```

you declared it like

```
nodee **head = NULL;
```

Within the function `push` when it is called the first time the pointer `head` is set by the address of the local variable `first` that will not be alive after exiting the function

```
        nodee *first = new nodee();
        head = &first;
```

So the pointer `head` will be invalid.

Also the function `push` has a confusing logic. What is should do is to push an integer value on the list. So its parameter should specify the value that will be pushed not the number of nodes that will be pushed.

That is the function should be declared like

```
void push( int data );
```

Pay attention to that if you have a one-sided singly-linked list then new nodes should be appended to the beginning of the list. Otherwise you need to define a two-sided singly-linked list that is you need to declare a pointer to the head node and to the tail node..

For the one-sede linked-list the function `push` can be defined the following way provided that the data member head is declared like

```
nodee *head = NULL;

void push( int data )
{
    nodee *mew_node = new nodee { data, head };
    head = new_node;
}
```

Comment: Okay Got it thanks

Comment: it should be nullptr and not NULL...